# Windows 10 on Xbox One

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, xbox360

The other year I saw a lot of info regarding Windows 10 coming to the Xbox (just Google for "windows 10 on xbox one release date" and you'll see many results). But so far I can only find ways to stream Xbox games to Windows 10 PCs, NOT actually using the Xbox as a piece of PC hardware in the traditional sense.

Does anyone know where I can get concrete evidence of Microsoft's plans to release Windows 10 for the Xbox hardware? I am currently using a Mac with a large Windows VM on it for development but am keen to:

a) free up some space on the machine and stop the MacBook turning into a frying pan when running a VM (it gets hot as kernel time is used up for the VM, oddly).

b) get dedicated hardware to develop on without having to resort to buying many more devices (that is, an Xbox plus a dedicated PC that will be mostly redundant).

Given the merging of the Windows underlying codebase into the Xbox OS (so that it shares code with the Windows 10 code), I would ideally like to be able to buy an upcoming Xbox One S and RDP to it to develop code on it, and also use it as a gaming device.

This would make perfect sense, as the Xbox is a 64bit Intel PC, just in a hifi-stand-friendly case.

Comment: Its not Windows 10 in the traditional sense.  And from what I just read, the Xbox is now powered by Windows 10 already.  But you are not getting the desktop OS that you get on PC.  If I'm wrong, point out where it is you read that you could do the things you are asking about.

Comment: I think you are right. Time to ignore the Xbox and get a Win10 laptop instead. Perhaps I was reading too much into http://www.techradar.com/news/gaming/playing-xbox-one-with-your-mouse-and-keyboard-is-not-far-off--1299880

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it will ever be a Windows console.  I guess if that's what you want, Alienware has machines to do that (the Windows version of the Steam machine).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Looks like I was hoping for too much from the Xbox! I could probably get a small format Windows 10 machine or a laptop instead then.

Comment: The current Xbox OS is already Windows 10, specifially, based on the Windows 10 Version 1511 10586 build.  The Xbox One **cannot** and will never run Windows 10 Home/Professional.